# Can I charge a battery and a phone at the same time?

Tags: battery

I'm wondering if this charging setup will induce any issues.
[image]

The wall is charging the left battery, which is charging the middle battery, which is charging the right phone.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at several battery manufacturers comments and they generally say NOT to do this.  If you think about this - if you are charging at 1 amp and at the same time pushing out 1 amp to a downstream device, how can the battery ever charge at all?  That also doesn't consider the inefficiencies of the design.  Generally the efficiency is supposed to be something like 35% so only 35% of the battery's charge could go downstream and I'm not sure of what the charge efficiency is.

Comment: Well you didn't mention anything stating it could harm the batteries, so what if the phone finished charging? Would the second battery fill up, and then the first battery fill up after without any harm?

Comment: Hard to say.  I checked with manufacturers like Anker and they only say - don't do this.  No mention of what happens if you actually try.